# Gradle, multiproject signing with gpg. Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed

Tags: java, gradle, gnupg

I have multiproject gradle configuration. I'd like to sign my artifacts before publishing. I do the following:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.10
}

subprojects {
    group 'com.example'
    version '1.0.0'

    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    apply plugin: 'signing'

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        ...
    }

    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }

    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
            }
        }

        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
        }
    }

    signing {
        sign publishing.publications.mavenJava
    }

}
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been
>   accessed.

I have no idea what does it mean. I use gradle 4.8.
I have 3 subprojects there.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with Gradle 4.9

Apply the signing plugin before the maven-publish.
Hope it helps.

```
apply plugin: 'signing'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I'm no longer working on this project, but if I'll find some time, I'll try to reproduce this at home and verify :)
Thank you!